# Cannot get role: 'style' to work with Column chart when using JSON with Google Charts

Tags: php, json, graph, styles, google-visualization

By following Google's documentation, I have been able to get a column chart to work fine with static data. However all the columns are the same color and I want to use role: 'style' to set the color as described here:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
    ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333'],            // RGB value
['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],            // English color name
['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ], // CSS-style declaration
  ]);
```

The problem I am having is that I can't figure out how to get this to work with JSON where the data is dynamic (it is pulled from MySQL using a script).

This is my code that does not display anything:

```
echo <<< END
{
"cols": [
  {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
  {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"},
  {type:'string', role:'style'}
],
"rows": [ 
END;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

  echo <<< END
  {"c":[{"v":"
  END;
  echo $row['DEVICEID'];
  echo <<< END
    ","f":null},{"v":
  END;
  echo $row['minutecount'];
  echo <<< END
    ,"f":null},{"v":"gold","f":null}]},
  END;
}
```

These are the two things I have added to try and get it to work:

```
{type:'string', role:'style'}
...
,{"v":"gold","f":null}
```

I can't seem to find a JSON example so the above declarations may be incorrect. Right now I have all them hardcoded to 'gold', but once that works I will be changing the colors dynamically.

Without these, the chart displays fine (with dynamic data) but with all the same color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem, it was this line:

```
 {type:'string', role:'style'}
```

When I changed it to the following, everything worked.

```
 {"type":"string", "role":"style"}
```

Comment: Were you trying to divide the graph area horizontally or vertically?